# Send a text as email with receiver (me) already inserted?

Tags: ios, email, swift3, uialertcontroller

I would like to give my users the possibility to send me improvement proposals (hope that's the word) by entering some text in a text field and submitting it. The process should look like this:

1. you click the "Improvement Proposal"-button
2. a UIAlert with a text field is opening
3. you enter text and click on submit
4. a new email is opening and with my email address inserted as the receiver

How do I do that? Well, I already got step 1 to 3, just step 4 is the point that I'm having trouble with.

Is that actually possible and if yes, how?

Comment: The term is typically "enhancement request".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is definitely possible by using [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller).
Then you can write

```
let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
//...further setup...
composeVC.setMessageBody("This is my proposal:", isHTML: false)
composeVC.setToRecipients(["myadress@example.com"])
self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```